# mysql fetch result group by column name

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my tbl_client:

```
c_ID    city       type         amount
----    --------   ----------   ------
1       Boston     Medical      1500
2       Miami      Educational  3000
3       Dallas     Scholarship  1000
4       Boston     Scholarship  1500
5       Miami      Medical      3000
6       Boston     Educational  1000
7       Miami      Medical      3000
8       Dallas     Medical      1000
```

how to fetch the result as this:

```
city          Medical       Educational    Scholarship
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
Boston        1500          1000           1500     
Dallas        1000          Null           1000     
Miami         6000          3000           Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggravated function `SUM` with `GROUP BY`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   c_ID int,
   city varchar(50),
   type varchar(50),
   amount int
);




INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'Boston','Medical',1500);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'Miami','Educational',3000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'Dallas','Scholarship',1000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'Boston','Scholarship',1500);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'Miami','Medical',3000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'Boston','Educational',1000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'Miami','Medical',3000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (8,'Dallas','Medical',1000);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT city,          
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Medical' THEN amount END) Medical,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Educational' THEN amount END) Educational,   
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Scholarship' THEN amount END) Scholarship   
FROM T 
GROUP BY city;

| city   | Medical | Educational | Scholarship |
| ------ | ------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| Boston | 1500    | 1000        | 1500        |
| Dallas | 1000    |             | 1000        |
| Miami  | 6000    | 3000        |             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5YRRuvux8pEAbYXJJdhWBj/0)

Comment: It works! Actually i have multiple table , awesome dude :)

Comment: how to set null- 0?

Comment: @UmandapJervy You can try to add `ELSE 0` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5YRRuvux8pEAbYXJJdhWBj/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city
    CASE        
     WHEN type = 'Medical' THEN amount END) Medical,  
     WHEN type = 'Educational' THEN amount END) Educational,   
     WHEN type = 'Scholarship' THEN amount END) Scholarship   
FROM tbl_client
GROUP BY city
```